# Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] Error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I asked many things like **ChatGPT**. However, none of them could solve this problem. I have a *Java* *Maven* project and it's on netbeans. I guess that's the problem. There is a problem with NetBeans. By the way, this project is a **Java swing** project (I'm making a desktop application). I would be very happy if you could help me. I spent all day doing this.

Even though I changed the location of the **hibernate.cfg.xml** file many times, the error was not corrected. I think there is no problem with **hibernate.cfg.xml** file. In order for it to exist, the application would have to find this file first.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgZXf.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6USt.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.